# storing larger real values creates unwanted results in SQLite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to store real value in SQlite. 
but when i insert the value as **1234.12 it stores 1234.12**
however when as i insert value as **12345.12 it stores 12345.1**
and below is some unnknow output

1. **123456.12 stores 123456**
2. **1234567.12 stores  1.23457e+06**
3. **123.1234 stores  123.123**
4. **123.12345 stores  123.123** (same as 3)
5. **123456789 stores  123457e+08**
6. **1.1234567 stores  1.123456**
7. **1.12345678 stores  1.123456** and further same result.

However i want to store what i am inserting.

so my question is how to deal with such kind of problem to avoid such unwanted results.

is that anything i can convert the precesion like ?

**convert(numeric(9,2),(#####.####))**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is [typeless](http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html), You need to store the data as string and convert to double while retrieving it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your values in plain sqlite with a column defined as real and a select replied all values right, so I think there is a missdefined variable in the android programming

Comment: can u jsut trell me in detail how do u did that?